# Android: I can't find getFullYear()

Tags: android

I'm using the java Date Class in eclipse for Android as getYear is soon to be deprecated and replaced with getFullYear but the Class doesn't have the getFullYear function... What do I need to do to get it??

Comment: are you sure that the method is deprecated? i do not get any hint/warning/error if i want to use it. what SDK/Android do you use?

Comment: @Marcel, you can see it is deprecated here - http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html

Comment: ah ok! good to know :-) then Markus Drösser's answer is what you are looking for...

Comment: SDK 8. In the Java.util.Date getMonth, getDate etc all of them pop up with the hint To be deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

`Calender statcal = Calender.getInstance(Locale locale)`

and then access the field `statcal.get(Calendar.YEAR)`. That should do it.

Comment: Nice one thanks. So to access the values var = statcal.get(Calendar.YEAR)

Comment: No that's fine, had a play and its working great for me now. Well tip for you then DAY_OF_WEEK now starts at 1-7 and not 0-6 lol however MONTH is still 0-11?? Mental... Thanks Again.

Comment: yes, this is a bit weird, i experienced it already when creating a timestamp for some files, but thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to use the result for display purposes, I would recommend using the android.text.format.DateFormat class in android.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html

You can simply do

```
DateFormat.format("yyyy", dateObject);
```

The dateObject can be a `Calendar`, `Date` or `timeInMillis`

Comment: That's also useful to know. Thank you.